# Code performance strick measurement

Tags: c++, linux, performance, clock

I’m creating performance framework tool for measuring individual message processing time in CentOS 7. I reserved one CPU for this task with *isolcpus* kernel option and I run it using *taskset*.

Ok, now the problem. I trying to measure the max processing time among several messages. The processing time is <= 1000ns, but when I run many iterations I get very high results (> 10000ns).

Here I created some simple code which does nothing interesting but shows the problem. Depending on the number of iterations i can get results like:

```
max: 84 min: 23 -> for 1000 iterations
max: 68540 min: 11 -> for 100000000 iterations
```

I'm trying to understand from where this difference came from? I tried to run this with real-time scheduling with highest priority. Is there some way to prevent that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <time.h>

const unsigned long long SEC = 1000L*1000L*1000L;

inline int64_t time_difference( const timespec &start,
                             const timespec &stop ) {
    return ( (stop.tv_sec * SEC - start.tv_sec * SEC) +
             (stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec));
}
int main()
{
    timespec start, stop;
    int64_t max = 0, min = std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max();

    for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i){
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop);
        int64_t time = time_difference(start, stop);
        max = std::max(max, time);
        min = std::min(min, time);
    }
    std::cout << "max: " << max << " min: " << min << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `CLOCK_REALTIME` rather than the appropriate `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`?

Comment: I've tried both and also CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID but with no big difference.

Comment: After another look at `man clock_getttime`, I'd suggest `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` if available.

Comment: AS future reference this documents gives some info:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-per-CPU-kthreads.txt

Comment: It would be nice if Kernel give some possibility to isolate CPU as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really reduce jitter to zero even with `isolcpus`, since you still have at least the following:

1) Interrupts delivered to your CPU (you may be able to reduce this my messing with [irq affinity](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/IRQ-affinity.txt) - but probably not to zero).

2) Clock timer interrupts are still scheduled for your process and may do a variable amount of work on the kernel side.

3) The CPU itself may pause briefly for P-state or C-state transitions, or other reasons (e.g., to let voltage levels settle after turning on AVX circuitry, etc).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I get it now. I will have to resolve this somehow statistically. Measuring set of messages several times, rejecting the highest and lowest values and averaging the rest.

Comment: You can likely get very _close_ to quiet, i.e., 99.999% of your messages are processed in the expected time. So you just throw out the very low % outliers.

Answer (score 1):

Let us check the documentation...

> Isolation will be effected for userspace processes - kernel threads may still get scheduled on the isolcpus isolated CPUs.

So it seems that there is no guarantee of perfect isolation, at least not from the kernel.

Comment: Good catch! Do you maybe know some way to isolate the CPU from kernel threads?

Comment: @PawelFaron I am not sure you can get an exclusive lock to a processor under Linux.